# How to access "self" inside the scope of a class?

Tags: python, class, scope, instance, self

I've crossed an interesting problem.

Suppose we have a class, and in its constructor we take a boolean as an argument. How can I define methods inside the class based on the instance's condition/boolean? For example:

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    if self.x == true: # self is unreachable outside a method.
        def trueMethod():
            print "The true method was defined."
    if self.x == false: # self is unreachable outside a method.
        def falseMethod():
            print "The false method was defined."
```

Comment: And why would you want to do this? Seems like it will only confuse users.

Comment: `self` is like `this` in other language. Its can be access using instance method only.

Comment: Define your methods in the constructor. And if you want them to be methods, give them a self parameter.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I've explained why I want to do this in the BrenBarn's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but you can define methods with different names and expose them under certain circumstances. For example:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, flag):
        if flag:
            self.method = self._method

    def _method(self):
        print "I'm a method!"
```

Testing it:

```
>>> X(True).method()
I'm a method!
>>> X(False).method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Answer (score 3):

No, because `self` refers to an instance, and there are no instances yet at the time the class is defined.

There are ways to achieve similar effects (like renaming, adding or deleting methods on a per-instance basis within `__init__`), but there's no real reason to do this anyway.

Comment: In an engine that I'm developing, I have a Grect class (grid rectangle), and it can be used as a background or not (The constructor takes a boolean: isBackground). If the boolean is true, I define the "addBackground" method so that the instance can reach it. I did not want an instance that it is not a background to have access to the "addBackground" method.

Comment: @EricsonWillians: There are better solutions.  One is to make a subclass for background rectangles and put the method there.  Another is to just give the Grect class the `addBackground` method, but have it check whether `self.isBackground` is true and raise an error if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, but to define a method on the fly you can use `types.MethodType`:

```
from types import MethodType

def trueMethod(self):
    print "The true method was defined."
def falseMethod(self):
    print "The false method was defined."

class X():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        if self.x:
            self.trueMethod = MethodType(trueMethod, self, X) 
        elif not self.x:
            self.falseMethod = MethodType(falseMethod, self, X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dict and on the bases of value you can access function like

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
    self.my_dict = {True : lambda *a : print "True method", False: lambda *a: print "False method"}
```

Then you can access `self.my_dict[self.x]`.