# Give class instances different methods depending on instance variables

Tags: python, class

I want to make a class where instances have different methods depending on their variables.

For example:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, eggs):
        self.eggs = eggs
```

then, if a `Spam` has a `self.eggs` of 5, it should have `foo` defined like this:

```
def foo(self):
    print(self.eggs)
```

otherwise

```
def foo(self, excited):
    if excited:
       print("{}!!!!!".format(self.eggs))
    else:
       print("{}...".format(self.eggs))
```

Currently, I am doing this by declaring both `foo` functions (with different names) outside the class, and setting which one an instance has as a method in `__init__`. However, this removes the function definitions from the class definition, which I don't really want to do. Are there any other ways?

Edit: actual context.

I am making some classes to represent nodes in graphs, where each graph can be weighted or not.
I want nodes to have a `link` method, taking another node as an argument, which connects them together. Nodes in weighted graphs (i.e. those where `self.graph.weighted` is `True`) should have a `link` method with another parameter that specifies the weight of the connecting edge. Is there a better way of doing this? For instance, making the weight paramater optional, but present in all node's `link` method.

Comment: Switching APIs based on state is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've edited the question to give the actual context.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: It sounds like you want a basic graph class, and to derive a weighted graph class from it. Or, if you decide that it isn't worth having an entirely new class just for a weighted graph, just have a `weight` argument for the `link` method which defaults to `1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access "self" inside the scope of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165529/how-to-access-self-inside-the-scope-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit what jme mentioned:

The default argument approach:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.links = []

    def link(self, other, weight = None):
        self.links.append((other, weight))
```

The inheritance approach:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.links = []

    def link(self, other):
        #one of the following, depending if other methods of this base class will be used in the derived class
        self.links.append((other, None))
        #self.links.append(other)

class WeightedNode(Node):
    def link(self, other, weight):
        self.links.append((other, weight))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `foo` only one method of `Spam`, with default argument `excited`:

```
In [49]: class Spam:
    ...:    def __init__(self, eggs):
    ...:        self.eggs = eggs
    ...: 
    ...:    def foo(self, excited=False):
    ...:        if self.eggs == 5:
    ...:            print(self.eggs)
    ...:            return
    ...: 
    ...:        if excited:
    ...:           print("{}!!!!!".format(self.eggs))
    ...:        else:
    ...:           print("{}...".format(self.eggs))

In [50]: Spam(5).foo()
5

In [51]: Spam(6).foo()
6...

In [52]: Spam(6).foo(True)
6!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to take advantage of a "factory pattern." That is, you need to have N classes (not all inheritance related but duck type related) such that:

```
 def create_my_class(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
   #optional arguments? Ah ha!
   if arg3 is not None and arg4 is not None:
     return MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
   elif arg3 is not None:
     return AnotherClass(arg1, arg3)
   else:
     return YetAnotherClass(arg1, arg2)
```

So you decouple the implementation of each class but not it's construction. You can then use (and substitute) this method to aid in the creation of different classes.

```
   node1 = create_my_class(1, 1)
   node2 = create_my_class(1, 2, node1)
   node3 = create_my_class(1, 3, node1, 15)
   #etc...
```

Comment: Hmm, I always get a bit suspicious with factories (the woe and doom of Java) in python. In your specific case, why don't you just implement `__new__` on the base class?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Well, in `Java` people went "enterprise" crazy. In Python we have functions and duck typing. So to add a `__new__` on a class would bind that class to whatever varieties of classes we wanted to create with the call. Doing it with a function like this removes the need to strongly couple different classes together via one common mixin or class.

Comment: Very true and good point. I still fail to see how the factory pattern relates to OP's question. He needs to link nodes together either weighted or unweighted. I personally think anything beyond jme's comment (inherit or default arg) is shooting with cannons at sparrows.